# How to tell if a view gets cached?

Tags: views, 8, caching

I assume that as soon as you add a contextual filter, that is not a fixed value, the View becomes uncachable since it becomes dynamic, right?

Is there a clear cut way to tell if the View gets cached or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assume that as soon as you add a contextual filter, that is not a fixed value, the View becomes uncachable since it becomes dynamic, right?

No.

That just means that the view's output varies based on the URL. Specifically, a query argument.

This is why we in Drupal 8 have the concept of cache contexts: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/contexts.

For the Views module to efficiently determine whether a view can have a cached version or not, we need to know ahead of time which contexts a particular view display varies by. So, upon saving a modified view, the Views module iterates over all plugins that a particular view display uses and gathers its cacheability metadata. It then stores it in the `view` config entity.

Concrete example: the "Taxonomy Term" view that ships with Drupal 8 core. It has a path of `/taxonomy/term/%`, with that `%` being a particular taxonomy term ID. Open `core/modules/taxonomy/config/optional/views.view.taxonomy_term.yml` and scroll all the way to the bottom. You'll see this:

```
page_1:
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    display_plugin: page
    position: 1
    display_options:
      query:
        type: views_query
        options: {  }
      path: taxonomy/term/%
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      max-age: -1
      tags: {  }
```

Note the presence of the `url` cache context. That describes that this view varies by URL, in particular by the value for the `%` wildcard in the `/taxonomy/term/%` URL.

Comment: [X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache is not at all related to a view being cached or not](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194138/how-to-tell-if-a-view-gets-cached/195078#comment-235722) Thanks for clearing things up with a detailed answer, it all makes sense to me now. This is a much more in-depth version of  [Berdir's answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194138/how-to-tell-if-a-view-gets-cached/195078#194163).

Comment: Glad it helps clearing things up! That was the goal :)

Answer (score 4):

You can read cache status inside the HTTP response header.

CASE: cache enabled

```
$ curl -I   d8.example.com/PathToYourView
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: MISS
```

CASE: cache disabled

```
$ curl -I   d8.example.com/PathToYourView
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: UNCACHEABLE
```

Comment: I created a page view called `test` with a contextual filter of Node ID with a fixed value of 1. So it always shows node 1 title. According to the HTTP response header it says Uncachable (O_o) https://d028t.ply.st/test if this is true then most views are uncachable?

Comment: Oh, turns out that view's do not get cached for Administrators (I get the Uncachable) but when being anonymous or authenticated user I get MISS or HIT.

Comment: Makes sense to me. As admin, I'm not interested in cached results.

Comment: The `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache` is not at all related to a view being cached or not. It's a header indicating whether Drupal 8's `dynamic_page_cache` module was able to cache parts of the page or not. See https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/dynamic_page_cache and http://wimleers.com/article/drupal-8-dynamic-page-cache.

Comment: This answer was not really salvageable, so I wrote a new one: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/195078/7632.

Answer (score 3):

If enabled, the view should always be cached unless you are relying on a certain field/filter/sort/... plugin that disables caching. For example a random sort.

Filters, Arguments and many other contexts are considered when defining the cache key.

You can see if a view is cacheable by looking at the calculated cacheable metadata in the exported yml file.