# How to tell if a view is cached from generated HTML output?

Tags: 7, views, caching

I have a view on my page and I've cached it using Views caching. Is there a way to tell that the view is cached from the output or the headers? [This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/194168/27174) says that Drupal sets the header `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache` but I don't see that in my browser's inspector. I do see the header `X-Generator:Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)` so that's nice.

It would be nice to see an HTML comment, like what the Boost module does.

Comment: What version of Drupal? 6, 7, or 8?

Comment: 7. Sorry, I should have specified. Mind you, I wouldn't mind knowing the same thing for 8.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you linked to is wrong. `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache` only exists in Drupal 8. Beyond that, the answer itself is also wrong. Will comment there.

In Drupal 7, you can't tell that the view is cached based on output (HTML markup) or headers.

Comment: Now commented there. Correct answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/195078/7632.

Comment: Ah! Thank you - I'm sorry I didn't notice that the question I linked to was tagged with Drupal 8.